# Ubuntu 16.04 no longer boots - black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, grub2

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 just fine for about a year. Recently I powered off my machine for a couple hours, and when I turned it back on, it can no longer boot into Ubuntu, it just gets stuck at a black screen with a blinking cursor forever.

To diagnose, I have booted with the boot-repair tool on a USB drive, and captured the boot-info summary. I would greatly appreciate some help in dissecting this information and helping me figure out what has happened.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/46y5NKy5GF/

/dev/sdb is a Samsung SSD which is supposed to be the boot drive, and contains the OS. /dev/sda is a WD HDD and just a data drive. /dev/sdc is the USB stick.

Comment: Use the "default repair" option of the `boot-repair` tool? That's what it says on the log you posted...

Comment: Use boot repair's default option. It's worked for me two times with a Samsung 960 SSD. Only side effect was extra boot options for Windows which I simply deleted.

Comment: Running the default repair has resolved the issue and I'm able to boot now. I notice that I am presented with a Grub menu every time I boot now, which was not the case before. It has a few options listed, but seems to choose the "Ubuntu" option after a few seconds.

Any idea what may have happened to cause the need to run boot-repair and how I can avoid this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

> => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
>      2048 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
>      this location.

This is likely the cause of your problem. Go into your system/hardware setting and disable legacy boot support.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would an MBR on /dev/sda be disrupting the boot process if it's the drive at /dev/sdb that has been chosen as the boot device?